# SQL Server 2012 Express redundant processes

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-2012-express

I have been having some odd issues recently during the development of a new web app. So I decided to have a look at SQL Server as a possible source of random hangs etc.

On looking at the Activity monitor in SQL Server Management Studio, I see that during the application's usage there are quite a few items building up in the `Processes` panel, all owned by the IIS Default application pool.

Now I have been careful to close database connections after queries and on page close, however these do not go away.

Is this just a list of previous processes, or are they all still alive??

I can right click -> KILL the processes, and they go away.

Comment: You don't want to "right-click,kill"!!!!

Comment: It's using the connection pool, that means a connection will hang around for two minutes (default) from the last time it was used. Unless you are waiting for exclusive access, this isn't a problem. If you want to manage the connections yourself (have a deep think about that..) add pooling=false to your connection string.